# Laravel 5.1 Find an item using eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have following tables.

### Users

id

name

### Events

id

name

### Cards

id

name

### Transfers

id

event_id

card_id

An user has many events and cards. An user can accepts cards from other user which he met at an event.A row  will be added under transfers table whenever a card is accepted by a user, this row links a `card_id` with `event_id`. I am looking for a way to check a card (`card_id`) is  added under the transfers table for a logged in  user's event(`event_id`).

eg:-

```
auth()->user()->events->transfers->where(([['card_id', '=',$cardid]])->find());
```

Can someone help me by telling what is the best way to handle above situation using eloquent?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `belongsToMany`-relation

Take a look at the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships